# show categories with its subcategories sql server (transact sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi
i have 2 tables category and subcategory

I want to show the category.categoryname and all its subcategory.subcategoryname

i'm using sqlserver 2005 and i want to show the result in datalist c# like this:

```
parent category 1
sub category 1
sub category 2
parent category 2
sub category 1
sub category 2
sub category 3
parent category 3
sub category 1
```

like this: http://parts.motors.ebay.com/Parts-Accessories/6028/

i've tried this

```
SELECT  distinct Category.CategoryName ,subcategory.subcategoryname  
FROM subCategory right JOIN category ON 
subcategory.CategoryID = category.CategoryID
```

but the categoryname repeat for every subcategory

Answer (score 1):

The display on the ebay link can be reproduced using a display grouping on CategoryName. The "table" control in SSRS is an example.

However, if you want it in SQL...

Because you are effectively appending rows, you need a UNION. Then you need a derived table (or CTE) to have extra columns to allow ordering

I can't try this, but something like:

```
SELECT
    bar
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        S.subcategoryname As bar, C.CategoryName AS SortName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CategoryName ORDER BY subcategoryname) As RowNum
    FROM
        category C LEFT JOIN subCategory S ON C.CategoryID = S.CategoryID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.CategoryName As bar, C.CategoryName AS SortName, 0
    FROM
        category C
    ) foo
ORDER BY
    foo.SortName, RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

repeation will be there.But You can ignore or remove it before binding to datalist.This you can do in code-behind in C# & Let your query be same,which practically right as well.